# Мячик выходит за границу =(

Tags: javascript

Создал скрипт, который передвигает мячик в центр, затем в правый край, а после в точку старта.
**Но почему мячик выходит за границу правого края?**
Ведь **clientWidth** по идее должен покрывать всю область элемента кроме границ и полосы прокрутки.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');   
let b = document.querySelector('#ball');   


setInterval(function(){

b.style.marginLeft = Math.round(a.clientWidth / 2 - b.offsetWidth / 2 ) + 'px';

b.style.marginTop = Math.round(a.clientHeight / 2 - b.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px'; 

setTimeout(()=> b.style.marginLeft = a.clientWidth  + 'px',1000)

setTimeout(() =>b.style.marginLeft = '', 2000);
        
},3200)
```

```css
#block{
background: orange; 
transition: all 2s;
border: 8px solid black;
}

#ball{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;   
transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">
<img id = "ball" src = "https://i.ibb.co/7jmdxFQ/23.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем Вы изменили код? На какой вопрос я теперь отвечаю?

Comment: Ну это я ошибки исправил =) Че вернуть как все было)?

Comment: Вернул все как было =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');
let b = document.querySelector('#ball');


window.onload = function() {
setInterval(function() {
  b.style.marginLeft = Math.round(a.clientWidth / 2 - b.offsetWidth / 2 ) + 'px';
  b.style.marginTop = Math.round(a.clientHeight / 2 - b.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';

  setTimeout(() => b.style.marginLeft = (a.clientWidth - b.clientWidth) + 'px', 1000);
  setTimeout(() => b.style.marginLeft = '', 2000);
}, 3200)
}
```

```css
#block {
  background: orange;
  transition: all 2s;
  border: 8px solid black;
}

#ball {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <img id="ball" src="https://i.ibb.co/7jmdxFQ/23.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Ну, я наблюдаю обратное. (Google Chrome)

Comment: А в чем разница между b.onload = function() и document.onload = function() ???

Comment: @Хмельни́цький В документации.

Comment: @Хмельни́цький, первое при загрузке этого элемента - второе при загрузке всего документа.

Comment: В самом деле мячик не двигается =(

Comment: @Хмельни́цький Зато "проще ... и заморачиваться не надо"

Comment: Ну чего вы троллите то =( Мне 14 лет, я изучаю js только 3 месяца

Comment: @Хмельни́цький, проверяйте

Comment: Лучше делать onload по элементу или по window? Как лучше и быстрее?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький, сам советую делать один window.onload. Что бы не было срача с кучей onload'ов.

Comment: И весь код на js пихать в window.onload ?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький, весь код - который должен запуститься после загрузки страницы.

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!

Comment: И еще последний вопрос. setTimeout(() => b.style.marginLeft = (a.clientWidth - b.clientWidth) + 'px', 1000); меня интересует эта строка. Если убрать скобки результат будет один и тот же. Какую роль выполняют скобки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129954/discussion-between-kotleni-and-).

Comment: @Хмельни́цький Не надо использовать Ваш нежный возраст как оправдание нежелания читать документацию.

Comment: @Igor, ну тут вы правы)